# SharePoint Birthday Calendars

Tags: sharepoint-online

For SharePoint Online, I have a group birthday calendar and I have been adding users birthdays to it but it seems to select the day before or after it and not the correct day. Has anyone else found a solution to this?

Comment: Your ask is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You said that "I have a group birthday calendar and I have been adding users birthdays to it but it seems to select the day before or after it and not the correct day."

What is group birthday calendar? Is it just a calendar list? Please offer a screenshot about your group birthday calendar and a screenshot about how you add users birthdays to it.

When you add an item in the calendar list, you can choose the date.

Comment: Hello Lisa , in modern pages you can add a "group calendar" a calendar created under 'Apps". Then you can call that created calendar into a modern page. The New calendar can let you Add Birthday events, but regardless of the day I select, it seems to have a glitch and would choose a day before or after. Even after I go back to update them it does the the same glitch. https://s8.postimg.cc/b8vlbmnwl/bcd.png